# Nginx config for Express SPA?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, single-page-application, ghost

I am setting up a Ghost blog which works as a React-based SPA. Everything's hosted on DO.

That means I don't have a great way to tool around with Express, which is what powers Ghost.

For my frontend, I need to always serve my index response, regardless of the URL.

This is my nginx config now, with everything working except the SPA component.

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

server_name SITE;
root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/SITE/fullchain.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/SITE/SITE.key;
include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;


location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2369;

}

location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}

client_max_body_size 50m;
```

}

I've tried many of the existing answers here on setting up Nginx for SPAs with no success. For example, `try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;`

Because I'm using `proxy_pass`, am I limited to this sort of behavior in my Express app? That would not be ideal because editing the blog code will break my upgrades.

Comment: In the SPA are you using the API from ghost?

Comment: Yes it is using the Ghost API.